# Awk $1 vs cut -f 1 - why am I getting different answers?

Tags: bash, awk, cut

So this question is bugging me and I have a million other projects to get to so I was hoping to clear this up. Thus far I haven't been able to find an answer. It seems pretty simple. I used:

```
awk '$1' merged_counts.txt |sort|uniq -d|wc
```

and got 216 lines. However, that number is incorrect. If I use

```
more merged_counts.txt|cut -f 1|sort|uniq -d|wc
```

I get 271 lines, which is correct. If I use

```
awk '{print $1}' merged_counts.txt |sort|uniq -d|wc
```

I also get 271 lines, however, then I've also lost the rest of the fields. I cannot figure out why it is behaving this way for what seems to be an elementary thing. Thanks for any help/suggestions. Surely I must be overlooking something.

Example of file:

```
B3GALT1 72  128 65  124 87  118 102 117 38  106 87  115 27  20  89  30
AMY1A   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
PSENEN  654 459 648 462 508 399 537 532 696 460 625 473 621 322 633 434
```

The gene 'AMY1A' is one of those genes annotated on both DNA strands so it appears twice in my file.

Comment: Btw, my question is why am I getting 216 vs 271. I know that using awk print will get rid of the rest of the fields. Thanks!

Comment: You are using `more` (an interactive program) where you should use `cat`, or even better, `cut -f 1 < merged_counts.txt`.

Comment: Bad habit of mine. Something in my head only lets me use cat if I'm actually going to concatenate something.

Comment: @user2937872 - good instincts on not using `cat` inappropriately, now you just need to work on developing the same for `more`, `less`, and anything else that uselessly opens files for other tools :-).

Comment: You say this number is correct and that number is incorrect but you never tell us why so we can't do much to help you other than telling you that all of the command lines above could be improved on. Tell us what you're trying to do with some SMALL representative sample input and expected output and we can help you, probably a lot!

Comment: I was trying to stay away from the biology of the question in hopes that my question would be clearer. I suppose that didn't work. Anyways, I know there are certain genes that are annotated on both strands because coding segments are actually contributed from both. Generally, this is not the case. It just so happens that the annotation reference I used doesn't give these transcripts different identifiers. Without getting too heavy, I'm interested in antisense transcription so direction is important.

Comment: Gosh, a down vote already? Stackoverflow is definitely not nice to those who aren't hard-core coders or who for reasons of data privacy try to be vague about certain details. Though a good resource, the general attitude is not very welcoming. To those who contributed to my small problem, I do sincerely appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see in a comment you say `I need to keep the entire line, but I need to filter for duplicates based only on the first field` so let's start with that and lets further assume that your fields are separated by any white space and that you always want to print the first line when a duplicate occurs.

The awk command you'd use then would be:

```
awk '!seen[$1]++' file
```

Now - update your question with a description, input, and output to tell us what else you need.

Comment: I've edited my question to give a bit more detail without giving too much away.

Answer (score 2):

`awk '$1'` (not to be confused with `awk '{print $1}'`) is going to print everything except lines that are either empty or contain only whitespace, or where the first field evaluates to a numeric value of 0. `cut -f 1` will not do this, and will include the empty and whitespace-only lines.

Comment: empty and whitespace-only lines are not a concern in this case. The duplicates in this 25k+ line file arise from genes that have been annotated on both the forward and reverse strand and therefore appear twice in my final file. Some I have been able to catch easily, others keep evading my scripts. :/

Comment: ... or lines where $1 has the value zero.

Comment: @EdMorton Good catch... Updated.

Answer (score 1):

`cut` uses a single character (`tab` by default, but changeable via the `-d` option) to separate fields, while `awk` uses any run of whitespace (by default, changeable via the `-F` option).

`awk '$1'` prints the entire line when `$1` is not considered false, not just the first field. This would result in fewer duplicate lines (since two lines might have the same first field, but differ in subsequent fields), and a lower line count.

Comment: Hi @chepner . I'm aware that I can change the delimiter in cut and awk. The thing is, I need to keep the entire line, but I need to filter for duplicates based only on the first field. I know there are 271 duplicates. The end goal is to append a short string to the duplicates for the purposes of another analysis where duplicate gene names are not allowed. I think I understand what you are saying about awk '$1'. But then how else can I keep the entire line but filter only on the first field?

Comment: There's a standard trick in `awk`: `awk 'uniq[$1] { uniq[$1]++; … }'` will only process a line when `$1` has not been observed before. The first thing it does is store that field, so it will ignore any future lines with the same `$1`.